How to make update operation in real time via flutter
import 'package:calculator_app/util/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class CustomBox extends StatelessWidget {
  String parameterName;
  CustomBox({
    super.key,
    required this.parameterName,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: Get.width * 0.45,
      height: Get.height * 0.1,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: sheetBgColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            parameterName,
            style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
              fontSize: 15,
              color: white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(color: white),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: white,
                  ),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: white,
                  ),
                ),
                hintText: 'Enter $parameterName',
                hintStyle: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(color: white),),
            onChanged: 
            
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


I'm trying to make this widget update the value of age and weight in a GetxController in real time but i cant quite figure out how.
I've tried assigning the controller parameters directly and also updating them with setters and getters.

The code is not complete. Could you please explain the issue you are facing?

So i want this widget to be able to update the controller value for a set parameter. I tried using onChanged for that but I cant figure out how I would make onChanged work since it only takes String values but I need to update an int value. I cant figure out how I'm going to set it up. Sorry its just as hard for me to explain.

Change your Widget to a Stateful Widget then add a setState onChanged

Change your Widget to a Stateful Widget than add a setState onChanged
class CustomBox extends StatefulWidget {
  String parameterName;
  CustomBox({
    super.key,
    required this.parameterName,
  });

  @override
  State<CustomBox> createState() => _CustomBoxState();
}

class _CustomBoxState extends State<CustomBox> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: Get.width * 0.45,
      height: Get.height * 0.1,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: sheetBgColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            widget.parameterName,
            style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
              fontSize: 15,
              color: white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(color: white),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: white,
                  ),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: white,
                  ),
                ),
                hintText: 'Enter ${widget.parameterName}',
                hintStyle: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(color: white),),
            onChanged: {
              //do something
              SetState((){});
            }
            
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

